# Click / getting ui.item undefined when _renderItem set

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am coding using jquery autocomplete and my intention is just to show a custom view with ( [Image] [Name] ). When I just use autocomplete code with standard renderItem (without set up it) autocomplete works perfectly but without image I want to show however when I set _renderItem it shows items perfectly but when selecting / focusing it I got ui.item is undefined. Could you please help me? Here is my code:

Using Jquery-ui 1.11.2 and Jquery 1.10.2:

```
$("#iSearch").autocomplete({

    source: function (request, response) {

        var psField = "produtoNome";

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Search/PesquisaParcial",
            data: "{'psField':'" + psField + "', 'psTerm':'" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                //{ label: item.ProdutoFoto, value: item.ProdutoNome }
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.ProdutoFoto, value: item.ProdutoNome, data: item };
                }));
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        $("#iSearch").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#iSearch").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    minLength: 2
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var produtoFoto = item.data.ProdutoFoto == null ? "../Images/semfoto.png" : "../Images/" + item.data.ProdutoFoto;
    var FotoHtml = "<img src='" + produtoFoto + "' width='35' height='30' />";
    return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + FotoHtml + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + item.value + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: can you share some sample data

Comment: Surething! This is the answer when a do a simple search. JSon below:
[{"Type": 0,"Produtoid": 138,"ProdutoNome": "camiseta ecológica","ProdutoFoto": null,  "Feiranteid": 30, "FeiranteNome": "Aluísio de Paula","DescricaoFeirante": "Camisetas ecológicas de garrafas pet", "EnderecoFeirante": "","Categoriaid": 8,       "CategoriaPaiid": 1,"CategoriaNome": "Moda","CategoriaPai": null,       "Descricaocategoria": "Moda","barracaid": 30,"barracanome": "Barraca 30","barracalatitude": -25.427026,"barracalongitude": -49.271824,       "FeiraId": 1,    "FeiraNome": "Feira do Largo da Ordem"}]

Comment: seems fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gxsmjx83/2/

Comment: indeed. Through fiddle it is fine however in my code I cant click and focus event is not setting dropdownlist value. I already searched for wrong libraries and tried to reinstall jquery. I am using VIsual Studio 2013. Do you know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found what was wrong!!!**

Well I will post here because it can help someone else who was having same issue. What I did to solve this issue:

1. Install through nuget jquery 1.11.2 and jquery-ui 1.11.2
2. I was doing some direct link to jss and css in my index.cshtml code then I have removed them from there
3. In BundleConfig.cs I just inserted reference to jquery-ui:

   ```
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
   ```
4. Put javascript autocomplete code in Index.cshtml script section like below:

@section scripts {
...Javascript Autocomplete code...
}

5. Happy Autocomplete working!